# Scala Play framework: Duplicate mappings of compiled css files

Tags: css, scala, playframework-2.0, less, sbt

I completed the [todolist tutorial](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaTodoList) and tried to extend it by adding a main.less stylesheet in app/assets/stylesheets. However, when I try to view the project in the browser with any or no rules in main.less I get this error, nicely displayed by the browser:

> Unexpected exception
>
> RuntimeException: Duplicate mappings:
>   /Users/franklinpearsall/Documents/Programming/play-2.0.4/todolist/target/scala-2.9.1/classes/public/stylesheets/main.css
>
> from
>
> /Users/franklinpearsall/Documents/Programming/play-2.0.4/todolist/public/stylesheets/main.css
>
> /Users/franklinpearsall/Documents/Programming/play-2.0.4/todolist/target/scala-2.9.1/resource_managed/main/public/stylesheets/main.css

For one, it seems weird that are css files inside target/scala-2.9.1/classes. Why is this happening? I googled around and couldn't find anything relevant. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Remove the main.css from the public/stylesheets directory. Seems like you already have a main.less file elsewhere.

Comment: Yup figured it out and this was what I did. not sure where that other  main.less file is...

Comment: Less is a css processor language. http://lesscss.org/ So basically what less does is adds a a lot of features to CSS making them more maintainable and dynamic. The Less compiler compiles the less files to corresponding css files which can be understood by the client browser.